# Executar plugin após ng-view estar carregada

Tags: angularjs

Estou utilizando o framework LocaStyle para desenvolvimento, dessa forma ele executa determinadas funções de plugins como jquery.mask.js e aplica nos elementos necessários.

Entretanto, algumas vezes acontece do plugin ser executado antes da view estar carregada, fazendo com que ele não tenha efeito sobre a página.

Como posso verificar se o Angular já carregou e a view e só então carregar o script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai ter de anexar um controller à página e ele executará o script quando a view carregar completamente, desse modo:

```
$angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl:'template/pag1.html',
      controller:'MyController'  //<- Controller anexado
    });
})
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
      //Defina as funções executadas assim que a view seja totalmente carregada
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode criar uma diretiva pro plugins jquery como explicado nesse artigo
https://medium.com/@fabyoguimaraes/sobre-diretivas-e-como-usar-corretamente-plugins-jquery-com-angularjs-8bcc5a07e371

Acho que esse éo melhor jeito